# Как правильно реализовать слушатель SMS сообщений при не запущенном приложении?

Tags: android

Есть android приложение, которое при включенном состоянии или нахождении в трее "слушает" SMS сообщения. При получении специальных SMS сообщений, приложение реагирует путём изменения элементов в главном активити и запуском "сирены".

**Проблема:** если приложение не запускалось после включения телефона, то при приходе SMS сообщения мое приложение никак не реагирует.

**Нужно:** даже если приложение не запускалось, оно должно реагировать на полученные сообщения. Если я не ошибаюсь, то приложение не может само себя запустить. В таком случае нужно выводить какое-то push-уведомление.

**Вопрос:** Как правильно реализовать данную функцию?

**Возможное решение:** насколько я понимаю, нужно реализовать Service (stickyIntent), который будет запускаться со включением телефона и "слушать" все СМСки. 
А что делать с уведомлениями? Я нашел информацию только по уведомлениям с Google Cloud или своими серверами. Можно ли реализовать уведомления локально?

Answer (score 2):

У вас должен быть `BroadcastReceiver` декларированный в манифесте с флагом `exported=true` типа:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" > <!-- 999 is highest system priority, so it's hack 2147483647 -->
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> <!-- pre kitkat action -->
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> <!-- kitkat action -->
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Обработка события должна происходить в ресивере этого бродкаста и если `BroadcastReceiver` декларирован как `exported=true`, то он срабатывает даже если приложение не было запущено ни разу.

Comment: Все так и стоит, единственное у меня не такой страшный приоритет) а всего лишь 1000, но я не думаю, что проблема в этом

Comment: Позвольте не поверить что не перехватывает такой ресивер. Я в смсках собаку съел так что увы не верю :)